# ValueError when setting array element with a sequence in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec

I'm working on a nlp project and trying to train an LSTM model for sentiment analysis using pre-trained word embeddings. However, I'm facing a ValueError when trying to assign word embeddings to a numpy array. Here's the code snippet that is my model:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Dropou

df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/machinelearning/processed_data_CLEAN.csv')

subset_size = 10000
subset_data = df.sample(n=subset_size, random_state=42)
processed_tweets = subset_data['Tweet'].tolist()

w2v_model = Word2Vec.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/machinelearning/word2vec_model/model.bin')

num_tweets = len(processed_tweets)

embedding_dim = w2v_model.vector_size

max_sequence_length = max(len(tweet) for tweet in processed_tweets)

tweet_matrix = np.zeros((num_tweets, max_sequence_length, embedding_dim))

for i, tweet in enumerate(processed_tweets):
    for j, word in enumerate(tweet):
        if word in w2v_model.wv:
            tweet_matrix[i, j] = w2v_model.wv[word]
        else:
            tweet_matrix[i, j] = np.zeros((embedding_dim,))

polarity = subset_data['Polarity']

processed_polarity = polarity.replace({0: 0, 2: 1, 4: 2})

labels = to_categorical(processed_polarity, num_classes=3)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(tweet_matrix, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

print("X_train shape:", X_train.shape)
print("y_train shape:", y_train.shape)
print("X_test shape:", X_test.shape)
print("y_test shape:", y_test.shape)
processed_tweets_subset = processed_tweets[:num_tweets]
vocab_size = len(set(word for tweet in processed_tweets_subset for word in tweet))
num_classes = 3 # for negative,neutral and positive


model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_sequence_length))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32,shuffle=True)
```

The error I got is this:

```
 ValueError: in user code:    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_3' (type Sequential).
    
Input 0 of layer "lstm_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (32, 152, 100, 100)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_3' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 152, 100), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

apparently there is an unexpected ndim (32, 152,** 100**, 100) that I have no idea where it comes from,I have verified that the word embeddings are of the correct shape and the array dimensions match. Is there something I'm missing or is there a different approach to assign the word embeddings to the array?

Comment: Is thet tha full error message you've received? Python errors usually display multiple frames of 'traceback' info, identifying the exact lines-of-code/files leading up to the error – unless that's been somehow captured/suppressed otherwise. If you can enable or show a full traceback in your question, it may help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Also, can you expand your question to include what your code is printing, from your shape-checking print lines, as well as add readouts of other relevant effective values, like `num_tweets`, `embedding_dim`, `max_sequence_length`, & `vocab_size`?

Answer (score 0):

Most fishy is that your network's 1st `Embedding` layer is sized to be exactly as large as your vocabulary - implying it's intended to take *word indexes*. Instead you're passing it your `X_train` where *every* element is already a looked-up `embedding_dim` (probably 100 dimension) vector.

That's likely the source of the extra dimensions in the error message.

Are you trying to merge 2 techniques that have different assumptions as to the source of the word-embeddings?

Might you instead want to somehow *initialize* the `Embedding` layer with the pretrained vectors for just the relevant words, in the right positions – then compose your `X_train` so each example is an array-of-word-indexes, rather than an array of word-vectors?

Comment: You were right! I removed the embeddings layer and used the pre-trained word embeddings directly and it worked, thank you very much!